# I Can't login to Instagram API Whit Unity3D App for Android/IOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instagram, instagram-api

I have a problem with log in functions on my app, made whit Unity3D for Android and IOS.
I'm actually using

```
Application.OpenURL("https:// api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/…");
```

and the answer from the browser is:

```
http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

I don't know how take this "access_token" from the browser URL and close the external browser and continue in my UnityApp

anybody have exp on Instagram API ?

I think to solve this issue it should listen in any port like `https:// sarasa.com:666/token=123123123123` and then on script listen the port `666` and take the token.

Any help would be thanked!

Comment: Possibly related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431427/instagram-relationshippost-api-is-not-working-in-ios-app?rq=1 ?

Comment: Hi all, well o can solved this issue using this asset from Store:

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/57532/release-notes

i so easy and cheap ;) 

thx all !!

Comment: Well, the In-App Web Browser works for iOS, Android, but not on Windows and MacOSX, unfortunately.